# Notify Lost DotsPageIndicator position

Tags: android

I made a GridViewPager with some Fragments.I have dots (DotsPageIndicator) that record position of the grid. When I want to change background color I use notifyDataSetChanged() and the position of the dots are lost. How can I solve this?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_teste);
    pager = (GridViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pager.setAdapter(new GridPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager()));
    dotsPageIndicator = (DotsPageIndicator) findViewById(R.id.page_indicator);
    dotsPageIndicator.setDotFadeWhenIdle(false);
    dotsPageIndicator.setPager(pager);
}
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            pager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use `android:keepScreenOn="true"` in the DotsPageIndicator *.xml file ? 
If you wanna change the background color of the different fragments that will be displayed by the GridViewPager: Have you tried to change the background colors of the fragments in the Fragment class without telling the Adapter?

Here is a link that helped me for implementing the GridViewPager maybe that will also be helpful: https://gist.github.com/gabrielemariotti/ca2d0a9f79b902b19a65

and the dots are just implemented like that for me:

in the *.xml

```
 <android.support.wearable.view.DotsPageIndicator
            android:id="@+id/dots"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center|top"/>
```

In the onCreate call it like that:

```
 DotsPageIndicator dotsPageIndicator = (DotsPageIndicator) findViewById(R.id.dots);
            dotsPageIndicator.setPager(mGridViewPager);
```

One last thing that could be is that when you change the color of the fragment it overlaps with the dots. That could be a reason that the dots are not shown. Try  to just change the color of the *.xml where the GridviewPager is added and change the color of the whole layout and set the fragments transparent maybe that makes the dots visible again.

Hope that was helpful!